# cannot import name 'PerlinNoise' from partially initialized module 'perlin_noise' error

Tags: python, matplotlib, perlin-noise

Heyo! i'm trying to visualise perlin noise, but i'm getting an error.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise

noise = PerlinNoise(octaves=10, seed=1)
xpix, ypix = 100, 100
pic = [[noise([i/xpix, j/ypix]) for j in range(xpix)] for i in range(ypix)]

plt.imshow(pic, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Pedro H\Documents\code\python\perlin noise\perlin_noise.py", line 2, in <module>
    from perlin_noise import *
  File "c:\Users\Pedro H\Documents\code\python\perlin noise\perlin_noise.py", line 3, in <module>
    from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise
ImportError: cannot import name 'PerlinNoise' from partially initialized module 'perlin_noise' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\Pedro H\Documents\code\python\perlin noise\perlin_noise.py)\
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems your current source file is called `perlin_noise.py` and in that same file you try `from perlin_noise import ...`. That can't work.  If there is some other file or library that contains the `PerlinNoise` function, you should probably rename your current source file.

Comment: oooh that actually worked thank you!